# Classification for color values - SVM?

Tags: algorithm, opencv, colors, machine-learning, svm

I am want to do a sky detection in my images. First of all I do a color segmentation to reduce unnecessary details and than I would like to use SVM to classify if the color is sky or landscape.

I use the HSV color space. I could use just a inRange function but the sky is not only blue. There are also white and gray and something between this.

Actually I use:

```
params.kernel_type = CvSVM::POLY;
params.degree = 3.0;
params.gamma = 3.0;
```

I train it with hue, saturation and value.
The results are not that bad but for example:

[image]
206, 244, 202 is wrong classified as landscape

[image]
88, 197, 195 as wrong classified as sky

So, is here SVM a good idea and I should go on with this or should I do more thresholding? How could I group these different values best?

Thank you in advance. Have a nice day!

Comment: What's the size of your train set? How did you chose the svm parameters? using cross validation for parameters selection usually help improving accuracy.

Comment: It also seems like you ignore some attributes you do have in your picture - such as the 'shape' of each cluster of colors, or do you use it somehow?

Comment: @amit: Around 100. SVM Parameters: Just tried out. And shape? What do you mean? That are very different (clouds, holes in clouds etc.)

Comment: About shape - I am not Image processing expert - but that sound like something you might be able to exploit to increase the dimensionality of the problem with more information, and as a result - probably get a better classifier.

Comment: Your problem is image segmentation. What you're doing amounts to a likelihood style term in an MRF (popular method), @amit is suggesting you classify the whole image jointly, in which case connectedness can be encouraged using a prior on segmentations. Checkout Pushmeet Kohli's work at Microsoft Research for example

Comment: POLY kernel is tricky and since is continuous it will try to fill gaps in your data. Have you tried with a RBF kernel? You have to be careful though, since you are working in a low dimension you have the risk for over-fitting so adjust your parameters to avoid that. Is the data public? Can we take a look?